# Show/Hide function folding margin on Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, text-editing, text-editors

Is it possible to get rid of the function folding margin on Notepad++? It seems like the sort of thing that should be in the prefs but I'm not seeing it anywhere.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In notepad++ v5.9.6.2 it's an option in the preferences. Under the "Editing" tab. 
They call it "Folder Margin Style". You can now select "none".

I think the more generic term for it is [code folding.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_folding)

Answer (score 0):

I found someone else asking [the same question on SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/forum/forum.php?thread_id=1934814&forum_id=331754)

The solution is claimed to be:

> If you go into langs.xml and comment
>   out the Language tags for file
>   extensions that you want, for me it's
>   PHP, Perl and VBS, then restart
>   Notepad++ and VOILA!!! No more
>   annoying folder margins.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Hmm. All that seemed to do was disable most of the syntax highlighting. The folding margin is still stubbornly stuck to the side of the window.

Comment: Well it's hard to find any reference of what your asking for :-( I wonder if Notepad++ calls folding margin something else...

Comment: There are no options for hiding the folding margin. You can only change the style of the folding margin, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this macro to the Macros section of shortcuts.xml to make a shortcut Ctrl+Alt+H to hide the fold margin. I haven't yet found a way to make the macro auto-execute, so for now you just have to manually hide it for each buffer...

```
<Macro name="Hide Fold Margin" Ctrl="yes" Alt="yes" Shift="no" Key="83">
    <Action type="0" message="2242" wParam="2" lParam="0" sParam="" />
</Macro>
```

See also: http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Margins

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings ==> Preferences ==> Margins/Border/Edge

There you can see, "Folder Margin Style"==> Select "None"