# Notepad++ Fold Icons Missing

Tags: windows-7, windows, notepad++, text-editors

I recently tweaked some Notepad++ settings and I somehow turned off the icons for folding code blocks. Whenever I open a JavaScript or C# file now, the collapse code block icons that are located off to the left side are missing. How can I turn them back on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. Preferences -> Editing -> Folder Margin Style -> Box Tree. It was set to none.

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/492429/23133 :)